# "It was extraordinary, she told herself, how this little snippet of a girl seemed suddenly to be taking charge of her problems,"

Tags: sentence-construction

> Miss Honey smiled. It was extraordinary, she told herself, how this little snippet of a girl seemed suddenly to be taking charge of her problems, and with such authority, too. "Well," she said, "that depends on what the questions are."

It came from the novel, Matilda

'It was extraordinary, she told herself, how this little snippet of a girl seemed suddenly to be taking charge of her problems,'

Is this sentence a 'how exclamation sentence' ??

and

'It is extraordinary, thought Miss Honey, how often small children have flights of fancy like this.'

Is this sentence a 'how exclamation sentence'  too??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *exclamation* is something like "How lovely!" or "How horrible!" and is written with an exclamation mark.

In your two examples, *how* introduces facts that Miss Honey finds remarkable, but she doesn't actually exclaim "How extraordinary!" *How* is being used in the same way as in "I will tell you how I know that," or "Show me how to do it."

Comment: okay. thank you .

Comment: but then,  what does it mean that 'It is extraordinary, thought Miss Honey, how often small children have flights of fancy like this.'

Comment: Miss H thought to herself that it was a remarkable fact that children so often have [flights of fancy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/flight-of-fancy).

Comment: thank you!!  please one more~       'It is extraordinary, thought Miss Honey, how lovely(horrible) small children are'    Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Yeas, that would be a valid sentence (I would expect it to continue  _...when they [behave in a particular way]_).

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with Kate, but...

There is a bit of 'in what way' or 'in what manner' of this kind of 'how'. As in 'how much'... kind of a quantity/quality thing.